# Analytical solution for a double integral involving logistic functions and Gaussian distributions

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, integration, closed-form-expressions, multivariable-calculus

I am working on a mathematical problem involving the evaluation of a double integral, and I am seeking an analytical solution or techniques to solve it. The integral I'm dealing with is as follows:

​$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty [L(C1+0.5w+0.5z) - L(C2+0.5w+0.5z) ] \cdot p(W=w \mid X=x) p(Z=z \mid X=x) \, dw \, dz$$

Here, $C1$ and $C2$ are constants, $L(\cdot)$ represents the logistic function $L(u)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-u)}$, and $W$ and $Z$ follow Gaussian distributions with mean $0.5x$ and variances $\sigma_W^2 \ll 1$ and $\sigma_Z^2 \ll 1$ respectively.

I am looking for an approach to analytically solve this integral or simplify it further, if possible. Any insights, techniques, or relevant references would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: there is no integration over $x$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes. There is no integration over $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Gaussian distributions of $w$ and $z$ are narrowly peaked around $x/2$, you can expand the logistic function around that value; to second order in the variance $\sigma_W^2+\sigma_Z^2$ this gives for the integral
$$I=(1+e^{-C_1-x/2})^{-1}-(1+e^{-C_2-x/2})^{-1}$$
$$+\left(\frac{e^{C_2+\frac{x}{2}} \left(e^{C_2+\frac{x}{2}}-1\right) }{8 \left(e^{C_2+\frac{x}{2}}+1\right)^3}-\frac{e^{C_1+\frac{x}{2}} \left(e^{C_1+\frac{x}{2}}-1\right) }{8 \left(e^{C_1+\frac{x}{2}}+1\right)^3}\right)(\sigma_W^2+\sigma_Z^2)+{\cal O}(\sigma_W^2+\sigma_Z^2)^2.$$
Other approximation strategies may be more appropriate depending on the parameters $x,C_1,C_2$.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't quite follow your solution since I'm not familiar enough with calculus. Could you please detail the steps a little bit? Many thanks!

Comment: expand the integrand in a power series in $w$ and $z$ around the point $x/2$, to second order; the zeroth order term is just $L(C_1+x/2)-L(C_2+x/2)$; the first order term vanishes upon averaging over $w$ and $z$; the second order term gives the quantity between large brackets times the average $\mathbb{E}[(W+Z-x)^2]=\sigma_W^2+\sigma_Z^2$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : You wrote the exact equality, $I=\cdots$. As such, this equality is of course false. If the equality is approximate, then in what sense, and why does it hold?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you for your comment. Do you imply that the equality only holds when $\sigma_W \rightarrow 0$ and $\sigma_Z \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you very much!

Comment: @Charles : The exact equality, as it was originally written, does not hold for any positive $\sigma$'s. Also, it makes no mathematical sense to say that the **equality** holds when the $\sigma$'s go to $0$. In this edited version of the answer, there is a displayed claim -- with a not quite clear meaning and without a proof.